# Is there any way to combine two collections into one and respond it?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I'm trying to do two find queries and combine the results into one array.

this is my code and it's not working

```
if (req.query.materialNumber) {
  MaterialStockItem.find({
    componentN: req.query.materialNumber,
    itemType: 'material'
  }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    var matStock = docs;
    StockItem.find({
        componentN: req.query.materialNumber,
        itemType: 'material'
      }),
      function(err, docs2) {
        if (err)
          throw err;
        var stock = docs2
        var combinedArray = matStock.concat(stock)
        res.json(combinedArray)
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you place some logs and check what you're getting in `docs` and `docs2`?

Comment: this is what I get from docs : Array(0) [] , but after the second find query the debugger drops but still running.

Comment: So you aren't getting any data from the first query. And probably an error on your second query,

Comment: man I accidenlty wrote a wrong ")" at the second query , now they are both working , it just the forkJoin that is going probs now:                                     import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
       Unexpected token

Comment: You'll have to use Rxjs for that. Also it only works with Promises and Observables I guess. You have callbacks. So it won't work in your case. Plus you don't need it in the first place. You code should work just fine.